# Need to create a report in Drupal 7 that counts Articles by Author for date range

Tags: log-messages

I am trying to create a simple display that lists all my authors who provided content to my site during a date range (i.e. Jan 1 thru Dec 31) with a count of the number of articles published, as follows:

Joe Smith, 120
Bob Jones, 87
Tom Kelly, 3

While the output is fairly simple, creating it is not (at least for me). I would think this would be a fairly common reporting requirement, so I'm hoping someone has already created it somewhere. If so, I'd love to use it on my site.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view by selecting users and add filter by date.

Comment: Workable, if not optimal. The Content: Auth ID is a identifier and it won't sort by that. But I can at least get that and the title of each published article, the cut-paste into Excel and get the work done from there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to cut past, just install view export module and download data in .xls format.